# Multiple Instances sharing the same database in a development environment

Tags: plugins, customization

I'm working with a team of developers on a new site and we've experienced an issue.  All of have a local install (under SVN) of WP 3.1.3 running on our machines, but we're all connected to  the same remote database.

The issue comes in when one of us creates a new plugin and installs it.  Until the plugin files are checked-in to the SVN repository, and the other devs check-out the new plugin files, WP will deactivate the plugin (since we're all on the same db, but different local installs) if it can't find the plugin file on another dev's machine who happens to be in the WP Dashboard.

So for example:

1. Dev A creates a plugin, and installs it.  The files are local on his machine. He checks then into SVN.
2. Dev B is in the dashboard, and hasn't gotten latest from the SVN repository so WP deactivates the plugin that Dev A just created since it can't find the files on Dev B's machine.

Is there any way around this other than each dev having a local db installed?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently had a similar issue, sadly,  the only way around it was either local database for each Dev team or all dev teams working on a shared remote environment.

Save your self the time and brain melt downs looking for another solution and pick whichever works better for you and go with it.

Answer (score 0):

There's an answer to a similar question [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/58573/sharing-database-for-collaborative-development/58581#58581). =D

You can create several `wp-config.php` files -- one for each branch of the project -- and commit them. Then you have to organize things to make sure that more impactive stages of the development (like creating new plugins) will be made in new branches.